# How to read a single date column in SAS?

Tags: sas

What's wrong with the below SAS code? The single date column cannot be read correctly.

```
DATA test;
    INPUT mydate MMDDYY8.;
    FORMAT mydate YYMMDD10.;
    DATALINES;
        01-22-98
        03-03-97
    ;
PROC PRINT DATA = test;
RUN;
```

Edit: Thanks for the answer. Another follow-up question is, when I try to read CSV format where datetime is quoted, it always fails to read correctly. How to read CSV format with quoted datetime values correctly? DSD option doesn't help much in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try left-aligning the datalines.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize this could be a problem. Any idea why datetime cannot be read if it is quoted in csv format?

Comment: Try adding dlm='","' to the infile statement.

Answer (score 2):

Though SAS is a free format language. I.e. Any statement can start in any line, one statement can span across multiple lines, multiple statement can be on online.

However with the datalines - statement that represents data within the code, data should start from column 1 / at least in column 2. Hence if the first two columns are blank, SAS assumes that the row is blank and goes to the next row.

Hence the mistake in your code is to start the data from the right column.